# Sort times array and keep unique values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $times array, which contains:

```
               array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "10:00"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "13:00"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "10:00"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "11:00"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "13:00"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "14:00"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "15:00"
}
```

How can I a) sort it so it starts with lowest value b) only have one entry of each time? (no duplicates, currently theres two 10:00s and 13:00s etc)

Comment: Have you tried using `sort()` and `array_unique()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use PHP's inbuilt functions:

```
$input = array_unique($input);
sort($input);
print_r($input);
```

Comment: +1 for beeing 14 secs faster than me because I needed to make links to w3 shiny ;-)

Comment: @Karem you don't copy and paste!

Comment: @MihaiIorga lol, no.. but now it works by doing $times = array_unique($times) , doing array_unique($times) only does not work. Thanks!

Comment: @Karem Most PHP functions (like array_unique) don't pass by reference - it would be pretty awful if they did.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always use the php-shipped standard functions for arrays:

[Array Unique](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp)

and [sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sort.asp)

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_unique(sort($a));
```